# smartgwt save image file instead show in browser

Tags: java, image, dialog, save, smartgwt

I've got a smartgwt application which create a link with a jpg/gif/png/pdf files. This files are shown in browser. I want to get the save dialog instead it which ask me the path when I want to save the file at local machine. How could I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, you have to change the response header by setting the Content-disposition to attachment. Like this:

'Content-disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg'
'Content-type: image/jpeg'

With these the browser will understand most cases that it should show up a dialog to save the image with the name: image.jpg. Also it might offer you to send it directly to an application, for example to an image viewer.

To get it work from a simple link, perhaps you have to write a servlet which will return the requested file with the correct headers and call that servlet from every link with a parameter to the real file.